# Change background color of JTable

Tags: java, swing, background, jtable, jscrollpane

I have added a table, but the problem is, the panel doesnt show its background color. I have tried setting scrollpane background color, etc. But it doesn't work. The frame has a button 'Verify', which when clicked, displays a table beneath it. Until it is clicked, the portion where the table will appear is solid gray. I want the whole portion to be ivory background. Kindly help me diagnose the problem.

```
try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection conn1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:vasantham","","");
    Statement st1=conn1.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1=st1.executeQuery("select * from try where DATEDIFF('d',NOW(),exdate) &lt; 61 order by tname");
    ResultSetMetaData md1=rs1.getMetaData();
    int cols1=md1.getColumnCount();
    model1=new DefaultTableModel();
    model1.addColumn("Purpose");
    model1.addColumn("Name");
    model1.addColumn("Composition");
    model1.addColumn("Expiry");
    model1.addColumn("Stock");
    model1.addColumn("Cost");
    model1.addColumn("Type");
    model1.addColumn("Supplier");
    model1.addColumn("Supplier Number");
    model1.addColumn("Rack");
    table1=new JTable(model1);
    Color ivory=new Color(255,255,208);
    table1.setOpaque(false);
    table1.setBackground(ivory);
    String[] tabledata1=new String[cols1];
    int i=0;
    while(rs1.next())
    {
        for(i=0;i&lt;cols1;i++)
        {
            if(i==3)
            {
                Date intr1=(rs1.getDate(i+1));
                tabledata1[i]=formatter1.format(intr1);
            }
            else
            tabledata1[i]=rs1.getObject(i+1).toString();
        }
        model1.addRow(tabledata1);
    }
    JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
    scroll1.setBackground(new Color(255,255,208));
    scroll1.getViewport().setBackground(ivory);
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel1.setBackground(ivory);
    table1.getTableHeader().setBackground(ivory);
    panel1.add(scroll1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame1.add(panel1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    conn1.close();
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Totally unrelated ... avoid querying the database on the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more info

Comment: @Robin This is a separate method 'addTable'. It must be called in actionPerformed. If not here, then where should I put it ,Sir?

Comment: The database query should happen on a worker thread to avoid blocking the EDT. For example the `SwingWorker` class can be used for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scroll Panes contain another component, known as the ViewPort.  This is actually where the components been assigned to the scroll pane get added.

If you want to maintain the JTable as transparent (`table1.setOpaque(false);`), then you need to change the view ports background

```
scroll1.getViewport().setBackground(ivory);
```

Otherwise, set the table to opaque and `table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);` to force the table to fill the entire viewport

**UPDATED**

Works fine for me

```
model1 = new DefaultTableModel();
model1.addColumn("Purpose");
model1.addColumn("Name");
model1.addColumn("Composition");
model1.addColumn("Expiry");
model1.addColumn("Stock");
model1.addColumn("Cost");
model1.addColumn("Type");
model1.addColumn("Supplier");
model1.addColumn("Supplier Number");
model1.addColumn("Rack");

for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {

    Vector vector = new Vector();
    vector.add("p" + index);
    vector.add("n" + index);
    vector.add("c" + index);
    vector.add("e" + index);
    vector.add("s" + index);
    vector.add("c" + index);
    vector.add("t" + index);
    vector.add("s" + index);
    vector.add("s" + index);
    vector.add("r" + index);

    model1.addRow(vector);

}

table1 = new JTable(model1);
Color ivory = new Color(255, 255, 208);
table1.setOpaque(true);
table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
table1.setBackground(ivory);

JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
table1.getTableHeader().setBackground(ivory);
add(scroll1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You can comment out the row creation section and it will still paint in ivory.

Comment: As you have seen I've already used your first option in the program. But it hadn't worked. I now set the table to opaque and fill the view port. But still it doesn't work, Sir.

Comment: @Gomathi Check my update.  I've tested and it works just fine for me

Comment: @Gomathi from you comments mKorbel, make sure that the frames content pane's background is also set BEFORE you build the table and from your code I think also the `panel1` should have it's background set BEFORE you create the table

Comment: Why is that vector used, Sir? Will the coding work only if I used it Sir?

Comment: The Vector is used because I don't have access to your database and need to see the results of the table when it was populated as well as populated.  You don't need it, it has no effect on the outcome.  My example maintains the opacity (true) and uses the `fillsViewportHeight` property

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. It worked fine when I set the content pane's background and panel's background BEFORE table creation. Thank you so much Sir.

Answer (score 2):

why do you mean doesn't work ???

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableCellClass {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Demo");
    private String[] columnNames = {"String", "Integer", "Float", "Double", "Locale & Double", "Boolean"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"aaa", new Integer(12), new Float(12.15), new Double(100.05), new Double(12.05), true},
        {"bbb", new Integer(5), new Float(7.154), new Double(6.1555), new Double(417.55), false},
        {"CCC", new Integer(92), new Float(0.1135), new Double(3.1455), new Double(11.05), true},
        {"ddd", new Integer(12), new Float(31.15), new Double(10.05), new Double(23.05), true},
        {"eee", new Integer(5), new Float(5.154), new Double(16.1555), new Double(17.55), false},
        {"fff", new Integer(92), new Float(4.1135), new Double(31.1455), new Double(3.05), true}};
    private TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public TableCellClass() {
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        //table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setBackground(Color.red);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.blue);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableCellClass tableCellClass = new TableCellClass();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this could be better, in the case that you want to play with opacity ???

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TableWithTimer  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    private JTable myTable;
    private String[] head = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"};
    private String[][] data = new String[25][6];

    public TableWithTimer() {
        myTable = new TableBackroundPaint0(data, head);
        myTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        myTable.setGridColor(Color.gray);
        myTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        scroll.setViewportView(myTable);
        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableWithTimer tableWithTimer = new TableWithTimer();
            }
        });
    }
}

class TableBackroundPaint0 extends JTable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    TableBackroundPaint0(Object[][] data, Object[] head) {
        super(data, head);
        setOpaque(false);
        ((JComponent) getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Color background = new Color(168, 210, 241);
        Color controlColor = new Color(230, 240, 230);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Paint oldPaint = g2.getPaint();
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, background, width, 0, controlColor));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
        for (int row : getSelectedRows()) {
            Rectangle start = getCellRect(row, 0, true);
            Rectangle end = getCellRect(row, getColumnCount() - 1, true);
            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(start.x, 0, controlColor, (int) ((end.x + end.width - start.x) * 1.25), 0, Color.orange));
            g2.fillRect(start.x, start.y, end.x + end.width - start.x, start.height);
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, when I click the button, the table appears with ivory background. I have no problem with that. But before clicking, the portion where table should appear remains gray, still. Maybe the problem is due to different panels, Sir?